# Accidentally pushed a tire plug all the way into tire. How bad is that?

Tags: tires, fix-a-flat

[image]

One of these rubber sticks. Pushed to far and dropped into the tire. Was able to patch the tire properly with a second stick. How bad is this? Weighs less than the screw that was stuck in my tire.

Answer (score 9):

You are correct - the weight of that plug is insufficient to cause any measurable disbalance and too soft (and too light) to cause any mechanical damage on the inside. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: After a few revolutions of the tire at speed, the plug is going to be permanently stuck in one place on the tire anyway. As you stated, shouldn't be an issue and even if it does cause a slight imbalance, it can easily be balanced at the tire shop.

Comment: |If you believe the advertising spiel from companies that sell "tyre beads" (e.g. "Dyna Beads") for automatic wheel balancing, it will should stick in the place that improves the balance rather than worsens it. (But the first "if" in this comment is a big one...)